# How can I exclude @angular/cli from npm-install process in a Docker image creation process?

Tags: angular, docker, angular-cli, npm-install

I'm starting a project that will use **Angular.js** and **Node.js** and it will be inside a Docker container. In my `Dockerfile` I've indicate that Docker must `RUN npm install` to configure my project when it will build the Docker image. This is a part of build logs:

```
Step 4/10 : RUN npm install
---> Running in 90d567c905d4

> @angular/cli@6.0.3 postinstall /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/ng-update-message.js

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})    

added 295 packages in 12.979s
```

I have installed `@angular/cli` package with **npm** in my OS and I don't want that the package `@angular/cli` will be installed in my project when Docker `RUN npm install`, it makes heavier my Docker image.

**How can I exclude @angular/cli from npm-install process in a Docker image creation process?**

To solve that I'm using this code in my `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN npm uninstall @angular/cli
```

But it didn't solve my problem. What you can suggest me?

Comment: I use it to start the structure of my Angular.js project.

Comment: Did you suggested that I don't need `@angular/cli` package to make my project?

Comment: Also, what you are describing doesn't really make much sense.  You want to use Angular-cli to scaffold your app, but you don't want the Angular-cli to be part of the docker image where your app is set up?

Comment: That's not the problem, the problem is that I have installed that package and it is installed automatically in my project when docker `RUN npm install` and I don't want that this happends.

Comment: Actually I'm learning how to use Angular.js, so I don't know. I want to make a web app with Angular.js and Node.js. I will use Angular 2.x.

Comment: you can use `ng-build`, then copy the contents of the `dist` folder over to your docker....

Comment: Thank you! That's sounds great! Can you write that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the comments talks about running `ng-build` and then using the `dist` folder in your Dockerfile.  *This is a step you can easily automate in your build*

This is the perfect opportunity to make use of Docker's [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

You're going to want your Dockerfile to look something like this:

```
FROM node:7.9 as build

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app/      # or wherever your source code is found
RUN ng-build
```

Here is the multi-stage part:

```
FROM nginx:alpine  # or whatever image you want here
COPY --from=build /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

Now you have a nice, small image, with only your `dist` directory, and none of the unnecessary overhead from running `ng-build` and `npm-install` in your final container.